# Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10

Tags: python, dll, tensorflow

Trying to install the gpu version of Tensorflow on my machine, but I'm getting this error when trying 'import tensorflow'

---

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
>        17         try:
>   ---> 18             return importlib.import_module(mname)
>        19         except ImportError:
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py in
>   import_module(name, pac kage)
>       125             level += 1
>   --> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       127
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _gcd_import(name, pac kage, level)
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _find_and_load(name, import_)
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _find_and_load_unlock ed(name, import_)
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _load_unlocked(spec)
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   module_from_spec(spec )
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap_external.py in
>   create_modul e(self, spec)
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _call_with_frames_rem oved(f, *args, **kwds)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w.py in ()
>        40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>   ---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>        42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import **version**
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w_internal.py in ()
>        20             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' )
>   ---> 21     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>        22     del swig_import_helper
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
>        19         except ImportError:
>   ---> 20             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' )
>        21     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py in
>   import_module(name, pac kage)
>       125             level += 1
>   --> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       127
>
> ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import tensorflow
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py
>   in  ()
>        22
>        23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
>   ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
>        25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
>        26
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py
>   in < module>()
>        49 import numpy as np
>        50
>   ---> 51 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>        52
>        53 # Protocol buffers
>
> C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w.py in ()
>        50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>        51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc ()
>   ---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
>        53
>        54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-
>   too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
>   ensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   imp ort_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 906, in
>   create_module   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
>   ensorflow.py", line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
>   ensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
>   ensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Users\snh5_000\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line
>   126, in imp ort_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
>   ems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Running Windows 10, Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.2.0 64-bit. Installed tensorflow-gpu using 'pip install tensorflow-gpu'.

I've attempted the fixes in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949, namely running Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 and confirming I had the following DLLs in System32/SysWOW64/my Python folder:

> KERNEL32.dll
>
> WSOCK32.dll
>
> WS2_32.dll
>
> SHLWAPI.dll
>
> python35.dll
>
> MSVCP140.dll
>
> VCRUNTIME140.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll

It's worth noting that the cpu version of Tensorflow imports and runs just fine, but when I attempt to use the gpu version I get the above error. I presume this is due to a mistake on my part in configuring the CUDA toolkit/cudNN, but I think I did everything listed in the instructions correctly. I made sure I had an entry in the PATH environment variable for the CUDA toolkit (leading to \bin and \libnvvp) and added one in for cudNN  (leading to \cuda).

Any thoughts or other information you'd need to help?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to rename `cudnn64_6.dll` to `cudnn64_5.dll` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin`.

Comment: Thanks Nova, this seemed to work. I also made sure to update my environment variables to match what Amar said lower in the comments.

Comment: There's an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9484) on the topic on github. Make sure you follow the updates.

Comment: I tried to rename from ``cudnn64_6.dll`` to ``cudnn64_5.dll`` and it didn't work. My mistake was that I downloaded cuDNN 6.0 instead of 5.1, and the [requirements section in the installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support) says that it only supports version 5.1. It worked when I used the correct files.

Comment: Indeed it needs to be version 5.1. No renaming is necessary.

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you need to use cudnn65_6.dll https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Comment: Refrain from changing the dll names! this is plain wrong and will cause other errors in the future. just use cudnnv6 as @ChrisBarrett also suggested.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have `CUDA_HOME` leading to `\cuda` and `%CUDA_HOME%\bin` appended to your PATH.
Also, tensorflow as of now only supports cudNN 5.1, please make sure you have that.

Comment: Thank you Amar! For anybody reading, make sure your environment variables match the above.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use cudnn64_6.dll https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Answer (score 3):

**Have you tried turning it off and on again?** 
Seriously, though. If you have your command line terminal running during the CUDA and cuDNN installs, the environment variables aren't refreshed until you close and re-open the terminal. I know it's simple, but I struggled for an hour before a simple restart solved that same import error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running Windows 10, Anaconda 4.3.21 64bit, Python 3.5.3, and TensorFlow 1.2.0.
However, the issue was fixed by installing cuDNN v5.1 instead of v6.0 as proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566341/3830240

Comment: This is the best solution, as the "renamed DLL" solution (posted by Nova) will cause you to encounter a binary incompatibility issue later on.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use cuDNN 6.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Answer (score 1):

I still got the `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal` error after installing cuDNN 5.1 (yes, I had PATH set correctly). I had better luck installing tensorflow_gpu from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow). This requires cuDNN 6.0, not 5.1. Unfortunately they currently only have Tensorflow 1.1 for GPU systems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions here and it wasn't working for me. Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support) for the requirements and make sure you have the compatible versions.
I also added all the cuDNN paths to my environment variables and also don't forget to copy the contents of *lib*,*bin* and *include* to the same folders inside your CUDA installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  I referred to the Tensorflow website to find the currently supported CudaNN version.  When I solved my issue, it was CudaNN 6.x.    The latest version, in my case 7 DLL is not loaded by tensorflow, and if you try to rename it, it causes memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that starting from version 1.0 up until version 1.2 `Tensorflow` needed Cuda8 and `cudnnv5.1`. Therefore You need to have cudnnv5.1 installed.
This question was asked on `April 24 2017`, This means the OP was trying to install version 1.1.0(at the time, the latest version) which at the time needed cudnnv5.1 and python3.5. So he needed to have cudnnv5.1 to fix his/her problem.

However, if you are trying to install the latest version of `Tensorflow`, that is anything greater than 1.3.0, you need `cudnnv6.0` +.
If you are getting this error on 1.3.0, then it means you need cudnnv6.0.
put that into your `PATH` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me trying to change dll file versions. After struggling with tensorflow-gpu import error for a couple of weeks, I finally figured out that I needed to make respective directories(CUDA,cuDNN & CUPTI) matched to my %PATH% environment variable. I am using CUDA 9.0, cuDNN v7.0 with Tensorflow 1.11.

```
C:\> SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;%PATH% 

C:\> SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;%PATH% 

C:\> SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu