# Tensorflow ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing the self driving course with Udacity.  There is a common environment which I launched in windows 10 and I was able to run tensorflow fine but I want to use the GPU.

My GPU is [listed](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) as compatible (GTX 950M).

I followed the tensorflow instructions on windows 10 to add the GPU:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

and downloaded and installed cuda_8.0.61_win10

Next I restarted my environment.  I checked to see it was working with the simple python program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create TensorFlow object called tensor
hello_constant = tf.constant('Hello World!')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the tf.constant operation in the session
    output = sess.run(hello_constant)
    print(output)
```

It executed fine as follows:

```
(carnd-term1) D:\SelfDrivingCar\tensor-exp>python hello.py
b'Hello World!'
```

Next I installed the gpu version of tensorflow:

```
(carnd-term1) D:\SelfDrivingCar\CarND-Traffic-Sign-Classifier-Project>pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (48.5MB)
    100% |################################| 48.6MB 16kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.2.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
Successfully installed tensorflow-gpu-1.1.0
```

I reran hello.py and got the following

```
(carnd-term1) D:\SelfDrivingCar\tensor-exp>python hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I removed the environment and repeated the whole process using the following command :

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

and got the same result.

The following doesn't work ([Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10)) as there is no file named cudnn64_6.dll in the directory listed.

Any ideas why the Import Error is occurring?

Comment: Just came across ``https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html`` So far so good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install cudnn. Only version 5.1 is officially supported right now. Don't know if the renaming trick for 6.0 mentioned at:

[Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10)