# DLL and pywrap_tensorflow missing. Tensorflow-gpu installation error

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu in anaconda environment (python version 3.5). However, I got a few errors, mainly:

- DLL load failed
- No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

It seems that this errors is quite common, however, I am not sure why the solution from the other question is not working.

1. I do have a `MSVCP140.DLL` in my path. I check this through `where
   MSVCP140.DLL`. This is a fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso).
2. I've installed CUDA 8.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and cuDNN 5.1 (and not cuDNN 6.0) from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).
3. I've added the path to `cudnn64_5.dll` (...\bin)
4. CPU version of tensorflow works well without error.

I've tried reinstalling CUDA and tensorflow-gpu but it still does not work. Any help?

---

Error message:

```
>ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


>Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

>See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

>for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem for a long time and seem to have solved it for me just now.

Install cuDNN 6.0 and confirm that the dll inside cuda/bin is named `cudnn64_6.dll`. Change only the name to `cudnn64_5.dll` (and make sure it is added to your path).

Hopefully this will resolve your problem.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10) is actually where I got the answer from.

Comment: Wow that seems to work! This is weird given that cuDNN 6.0 is not supported yet by Tensorflow. Maybe I'm wrong. Thank you very much though.