# No Module Named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, windows, dll, tensorflow

While trying to validate the installation of tensorflow-gpu, I get an ImportError when trying to execute "import tensorflow as tf". I am using a Quadro K620 on Windows 7. Tensorflow was installed using pip.

The following is the stack trace:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\aagarwal>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_hel
per
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_hel
per
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_hel
per
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packag
es\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_hel
per
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\aagarwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I have looked at multiple other stack overflow posts which things like correcting the path but I have not been able to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across the same issue today, please switch to cuDNN v5.1 Library for Windows instead as @mickdelaney suggested and then try to

1. Check environment settings of CUDA, normally all the settings of CUDA had been added to Windows environment
2. Copy files in `bin`, `lib` and `include` of cuDNN to `bin`, `lib` and `include` of CUDA respectively. Normally the directory is `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA`

And then you can import tensorflow and run your code. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution for the CPU: It worked for me

Just run below command if necessary then update it

`pip install tensorflow==1.5`

Comment: Though `pip install tensorflow==1.15.0` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

you could uninstall the current version of tensorflow and try a low version such as TensorFlow 0.12 using the code

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

https://blog.csdn.net/baidu_36669549/article/details/79734590

Answer (score 2):

After you install the CUDA Drivers you must download cuDNN and release it. After that you get to copy the `cudnn64_5.dll` to PATH.
If that doesn't work, move the `cudnn64_5.dll` to 
`NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin` and try it again. Otherwise you'd meet some error that you see.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

switch to cuDNN 5.1 instead of 6.0

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with anaconda, it was previously installed with another program through anaconda. Installing again through `conda-forge` worked:  `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

I still got this error after installing cuDNN 5.1 (yes, I had PATH set correctly). I had better luck installing tensorflow_gpu from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow). This requires cuDNN 6.0, not 5.1. Unfortunately they currently only have Tensorflow 1.1 for GPU systems.

Answer (score 0):

I am a chinese, so my english is poor, and my answer is that however you use cudnn 7 or 6 or 5 , you must rename the dll from cudnn64_x.dll to cudnn64_6.dll after you copy files.
maybe soon, you need to rename the dll to 7 or 8 or 9 as possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is all about your video chip/card and CPU compatibility with TF VERSION! Current version of Tensor Flow is 1.8 and it crashes on both my machines.

I have a win7 Gateway notebook using an I5 CPU and intel video chip. I have a desktop win7 unit with AMD Phenom II and AMD Radeon HD5450 video card. The I5 notebook requires V1.6 of TensorFlow and the desktop AMD unit takes V1.5. I don't have a GPU available for running ANN's so I don't know how that would affect it.

Here's the command line for PIP install: pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.5.0 (or whatever other version you need). This will uninstall your current version and then install the indicated version.

Build or copy a small TensorFlow script and run it in a command window. Open a second command window and install a different version. I'd recommend starting at 1.5 and working your way up.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me (Windows 10) is:
Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53840)
If you have a new fresh computer setup this one might miss.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after doing this command :

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu == 1.15.5
```

I was previously with tensorflow-gpu 1.15.0 when it was showing the error

Answer (score 0):

On macOS,

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.5.0`

worked for me.