# No Module Named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' (still without working solution)

Tags: python, windows, gpu, tensorflow

I have the same problem as in [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080677/no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal) and tried the proposed solution, but it did not work. Below you can find the stacktrace. I am on Windows 10 x64 with Python 3.5.2 and GPU NVidia Geforce 1050. I also checked the TensorFlow site for [common errors](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#CommonInstallationProblems).

```
C:\Users\Steph>ipython
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import tensorflow
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             return importlib.import_module(mname)
     19         except ImportError:

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in module_from_spec(spec)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in create_module(self, spec)

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     20             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
---> 21     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
     21     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a649b509054f> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     22
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50
     51 # Protocol buffers

c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53
     54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "c:\users\steph\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I am working on a research problem within Algorithmic Trading and need GPU support to speed up learning. I very much welcome any solution to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Module Named '\_pywrap\_tensorflow\_internal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080677/no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal)

Comment: Please have a look at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11571#issuecomment-316298725. The problem could have been with PATH variable not containing Visual Studio directories directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin\amd64, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this is due to missing DLLs (or missing paths thereto).

@mrry mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526626/issues-running-tensorflow#comment76047812_44526626) his helpful script to diagnose this kind of error, which you can find [there](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c).

Comment: `ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.

- Python version is 3.5.

- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Users\Steph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow

- All required DLLs are present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues`

Comment: Hard luck. I suggest you do open an issue on GitHub. Please come and update us with the answer when you get one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to cuda\bin directory in file explorer
rename the single dll file to cudnn64_5.dll
Done.