# Can't import tensorflow on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

**EDIT: After user1735003's comment on how the tensforflow documentation explicitly states that it supports only Python 3.5.x on Windows, I removed the earlier 3.6.2 version and installed 3.5.2 isntead. I get the same error, though.**

I have a **Windows 7 professional x64**, using **Python 3.5.2**. When I try to import tensorflow, I get the follwoing error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <m
odule>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49
, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Python installed at: `C:\Users\Ritwik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe`

I've installed tensorflow using pip as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

**I don't have an NVIDIA GPU.**

Comment: Try to remove python and install from scratch

Comment: Sorry, but everything (including Python) was a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows):

> TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows.

**EDIT**

See a generic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091193/1735003) for `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal` errors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the earlier Python installation, intalled 3.5.2 and still get the same error though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I checked out the script and installed a missing Visual C++ update and it worked!