# ImportError importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

While importing `tensorflow` i'm getting an error:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Module Named '\_pywrap\_tensorflow\_internal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080677/no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line in your trace back `"C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py"` I come to the conclusion that you are using python 3.7, python 3.7 doesn't support tensorflow as of yet, also it looks like you upgraded from python 3.6 given you didn't face a `no module named tensorflow` during your pip install.

The only solution is to work with python 3.6 as of now, so you will either need to downgrade your python or install conda and create an environment with python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is not supported on Python 3.7:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022