# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime: error while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

### I installed tensorflow 1.12.0.while impoting tensorflow in python3.9.1..faced error below

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
> in swig_import_helper()
> 17         try:
> ---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
> 19         except ImportError:
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\imp.py in
> find_module(name, path)
> 295     else:
> --> 296         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
> 297
>
> ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 57
> ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> 59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import **version**
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
> in 
> 27             return _mod
> ---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> 29     del swig_import_helper
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
> in swig_import_helper()
> 19         except ImportError:
> ---> 20             import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
> 21             return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 import tensorflow
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py
> in 
> 22
> 23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
> ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
> 25
> 26 try:
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py
> in 
> 47 import numpy as np
> 48
> ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
> 50
> 51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper
>
> c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> 73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
> ---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
> 75
> 76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 18, in swig_import_helper
> fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
> File
> "c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\imp.py",
> line 296, in find_module
> raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in 
> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in 
> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "c:\users\renis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 20, in swig_import_helper
> import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

​please help to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Module Named '\_pywrap\_tensorflow\_internal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080677/no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal)

Answer (score 0):

`Python 3.9` requires `Tensorflow 2.5` or later. You need to upgrade the Tensorflow version as per python.

You can use below code to upgrade the tensorflow:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) to check and install compatible Tensorflow version.