# Running older version of TensorFlow on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tensorflow, windows-10

I'm having a problem running TensorFlow 1.2 on Python 2.7 here
I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

I've tried many ways to resolve this problem, including this [Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10/) solution, but it doesn't work

I got the TensorFlow 1.2 from this [Google storage](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/), and currently using Python 2.7.13

I'm trying to get this [BiMPM](https://github.com/zhiguowang/BiMPM) running

I've checked my PATH, and everything's seems to be alright

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run tensorflow from tensorflow source directory. Try by changing the working directory.